# Displaying Username in Swift and FireBase

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to display the users username that stored in firebase. I'm not sure if Im saving the username correctly or if that's even the problem. I can't seem to access the data or display it at all. Any tips? I have a screenshot of the Cloud Firestore attached.

SignupViewController

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import AVKit
import FirebaseFirestore
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
var videoPlayer:AVPlayer?

var videoPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer?

@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var BackButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var UserNameTextField: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    setupElements()        
}

func setupElements(){
    
    //hides the error label
    errorLabel.alpha = 0
    //styles the text and buttons
            
    Utilities.styleTextField(UserNameTextField)
    Utilities.styleTextField(firstNameTextField)
    Utilities.styleTextField(lastNameTextField)
    Utilities.styleTextField(passwordTextField)
    Utilities.styleTextField(emailTextField)
    Utilities.styleFilledButton(signUpButton)      
}    

/*
// MARK: - Navigation


  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
 // this function makes sure all data is good
func validateFields() -> String?
{
    //make sure fields are filled
       if firstNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) ==             "" || lastNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || UserNameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == ""
    {
        return "Please fill all fields"
    }
    
    let cleanPassword = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    if Utilities.isPasswordValid(cleanPassword) == false{
        return "Needs 8 charaters, number, and special charater"
    }
    
    return nil
    
    
    
    
}


@IBAction func signUpTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    //validate fields
   
    let error = validateFields()
    
    if error != nil{
       showError(error!)
    }
    else{
        
        let firstName = firstNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let lastName = lastNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let username = UserNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
   
        //create user
            
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, err in
                if err != nil{
                    
                    self.showError("Error creating user")
                }
                
                else
                {
                    //User is stored sucessfully, store the first and last name
                  
                    let database = Firestore.firestore()
                 
                 
                    database.collection("UserInfo").addDocument(data: ["firstname": firstName,"email": email, "lastname": lastName, "username": username, "uid": result!.user.uid]) {(error) in
                       
                        
                    
                        if error != nil
                        {
                            self.showError("First name and last name couldnt be saved.")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.transitionToHome()
                }
                
            
            }
        }
        
      
        
        
    }

    
    
    
   
    

func showError(_ message:String){
    
    
    errorLabel.text = message
    errorLabel.alpha = 1
    

    
 }
    func transitionToHome(){
    
    let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.StoryBoard.homeViewController) as?
        HomeViewController
    
    
    view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    
}




override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    //Set up video in background
    
    
    setUpVideo()
    
}

func setUpVideo(){
    
    
    //Get path to resource bundle
   let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IMG_7211 2", ofType: "mov")
    
    guard bundlePath != nil else{
        return
    }
    //create the url from it
    
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!)
    
    
    
    //Create The video Player item
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    //create the player

    
    
    videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
   
    
    
    //create the layer
   
    
    
    videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer!)
  
    
    
    //adjust the size and frame
    
    videoPlayerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: -self.view.frame.size.width*1.5, y:0, width: self.view.frame.size.width*4, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    
    view.layer.insertSublayer(videoPlayerLayer!, at: 0)
    
    //add and play
    
    videoPlayer?.playImmediately(atRate: 0.8)
}







}
```

CurrentUser.swift

```
import Foundation

struct CurrentUser{
let uid: String
let name: String
let email: String
let profilepictureURL:String


init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]){
    self.uid = uid
    self.name = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
    self.profilepictureURL = dictionary["profilepictureURL"] as? String ?? ""
}
}
```

ProfileViewController

```
 import UIKit
  import Firebase
 import FirebaseAuth
 import FirebaseInstallations
 import FirebaseFirestore
 import FirebaseStorage
 import FirebaseDatabase
   class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var SignOut: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserNameLabel()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func UserNameLabel()
{
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil
    {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {return}
            
            let user = CurrentUser(uid: uid, dictionary: dict)
            
            self.UserName.text = user.username
            
        }
                
    }

  
    
}

@IBAction func SignOut(_ sender: Any) {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
           do {
               try Auth.auth().signOut()
               let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Vc")
               vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
               present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

           }
        catch let error as NSError {
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
}
         }
```

[image: Screenshot of cloud fire store]

Comment: from there what should I do? its still new to this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are saving the data to Firebase Firestore, and then trying to access it from firebase real time database. Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Firestore are 2 completely different backend servers and you are trying to use both at the same time. You need to pick only 1 and stick with it.

You are saving it to firebase firestore by using:

```
 let database = Firestore.firestore()
 database.collection("UserInfo").addDocument()
```

then after you save it to firestore you are trying to access it from real time database, not Firestore which is causing it to return nil:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
```

So instead what you need to do is get it back from firestore by using this:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("s").getDocuments { query, error in
for doc in query!.documents {
    // Successfully retrieved data from firestore.
}
```

}

Note: You could also instead save it to the real time database instead of firestore, but it just depends which one will work better for your app. You need to pick either Firestore or the Database, **you can't use both.** Here is more info to help you decide which one is better. [More Info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)

Comment: im still bit new but where to I go from there